# Failing to check if result of query is nil

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a query that checks if a phoneNumber exists in the child "visitors". If the phoneNumber exists, it adds the key of the child to the variable `visitorID`
If the `visitorID != ""` I get the code to do what I want, but when `visitorID == ""` I cannot get the code to do anything. Here's my best effort:

```
ref?.child("visitors").queryOrdered(byChild: "phoneNumber").queryEqual(toValue: phoneNumber).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapShot) in

   if let snapDict = snapShot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
       var visitorID = String()        
       for each in snapDict{
           let key  = each.key as! String               
           visitorID = key    
       }

       if visitorID != "" {        
           //Do something       
       } else {         
           //Do something else        
       }    
   }    
}, withCancel: {(Err) in
    print(Err.localizedDescription)
})
```

Comment: Why are you assigning a value to the same variable for each iteration of the loop without using the variable for anything, is it intentional to only keep the last value (if so this can be done more efficient)?

Comment: The code doesn't really do anything. You're querying for a phone number and if any nodes are found that match, they are returned in the snapshot. They would all have a key since they exist so there would never be a situation where a key is an empty string. And also what @JoakimDanielson said above, you're reading every key returned and assigning it to visitorID but then never do anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform a query and determine if there are any results, snapshot.exists is what you want

```
ref?.child("visitors").queryOrdered(byChild: "phoneNumber").queryEqual(toValue: phoneNumber).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

   if snapshot.exists() {
      print("found at least one")
      //do something with snapshot
   } else {
      print("non found, returning")
      return
   }

}, withCancel: {(Err) in
    print(Err.localizedDescription)
})
```

or

```
ref?.child("visitors").queryOrdered(byChild: "phoneNumber").queryEqual(toValue: phoneNumber).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

   if snapshot.exists() == false {
      print("none found, returning")
      return
   }
   //do something with snapshot
```